# Probability of a finite cylinder set in a free group

Tags: pr.probability, measure-theory, ergodic-theory, markov-chains, free-groups

Let $\mathbb{F}_n$ be the free group (each elemen is in its reduced form) generated by the set $\Sigma_n = \{a_1, a_2, \cdots, a_n, a_1^{-1}, a_2^{-1}, \cdots, a_n^{-1}\}$ and let $e$ denote the identity. For an element $v\in\mathbb{F}_n$, let $v[k]$ denote the value at $k$-th coordinate. For instance, $a_1^5[3] = a_i$. Because each word is reduced, we will NOT have $v[k] = e$. Now define a probability, for each $k\in\mathbb{N}$:

$$
P[v[k+1] = a_j\,\vert\,v[k] = a_i] = \begin{cases}p_{i, j}, k <\,\text{length of} \,\,v\\0, k \geq\,\text{length of}\,\,v \end{cases}
$$

Let $\mathbb{P} = [p_{i, j}]_{-n \leq i \leq n, -n \leq j \leq n}$ be the transition matrix. In this case, each $v$ is viewed as a concatenation of a countable sequence of letter from $\Sigma_n$ (or a concatenation of an element from $\Sigma_n^{\mathbb{N}}$).

Could anyone help find out a formula for the probability $P[v[k_1] = d_{k_1}, \cdots, v[k_n] = d_{k_n}]$ where $\{d_{k_1}, \cdots, d_{k_n}\}\subseteq\Sigma_n$ and $1 \leq k_1 < k_2 < \cdots < k_n$. I can only see the probability $P[v[n+k] = a_i\,\vert\,v[n+k] = a_j\,$for some $k\in\mathbb{N}$] is $\sum_{n\geq 1}\mathbb{P}^n[i, j]$. For a fixed $k\in\mathbb{N}$, is it true that

$$
P(v[n] = a_i\,\vert\,v[n+k] = a_j) = P(v[1] = a_i\,\vert\,v[k+1] = a_j) = \sum_{-n \leq l \leq n}\sum_{n \geq 1}\mathbb{P}^n[i, l]\mathbb{P}^k[l, j]
$$

In general, what is the formula for the following:
$$
\begin{aligned}
\begin{split}
&P(v[1] = a_i\,\vert\,v[k+1] = a_j\,\text{and length of }v\,\text{is}\,n) (n > k)\\
&P(v[n_1] = d_{n_1}, v[n_2] = d_{n_2}, \cdots, v[n_k] = d_{n_k})\,\,(\{d_{n_1}, d_{n_2}, \cdots, d_{n_k}\}\subseteq\Sigma_n\,\,\text{and}\,\,n_1 < n_2 < \cdots < n_k)\\
\end{split}
\end{aligned}
$$